# Trying to implement MATLAB $\tt pwelch$ in Python

Tags: matlab, fft, power-spectral-density, scipy

I'm implementing an existing MATLAB script in Python and noticing some differences in the behaviour of MATLAB's `pwelch` function compared to `scipy.signal.welch`.

From the docs, [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) uses a default window size of 256, whereas MATLAB's `pwelch` doc says:

> By default, x is divided into the longest possible segments to obtain as close to but not exceed 8 segments with 50% overlap".

Both use Hamming windows and overlap by 50%, so I assume the differences I'm seeing are due to window sizes.

However, if I set the same window size for both, I still see different frequency resolution in the results. e.g. for data series of length 6144, sampled every 0.292969 seconds, and set window size as follows:

```
n = 1000
freqs, power = signal.welch(timeseries, fs=1.0/0.292969, scaling='density', nperseg=n)
print(freqs[2]) # output 0.0034

n = 1500
freqs, power = signal.welch(timeseries, fs=1.0/0.292969, scaling='density', nperseg=n)
print(freqs[2]) # output 0.00227555370371
```

for MATLAB:

```
n = 1000;
dt = 0.292969;
[psd,freq] = pwelch(timeseries,n,[],[],1/dt);
freq(2) % output 0.0033

n = 1500;
[psd,freq] = pwelch(timeseries,n,[],[],1/dt);
freq(2) % output 0.0017
```

For higher window size the difference in output resolution is quite stark, and results in quite different amplitudes for peaks in the spectrum. Am I missing some other parameter which needs adjusting?

Comment: It looks like nfft might need adjusting... MATLAB uses the higher of 256 or the next power of 2 greater than the window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an oversight on my part - I needed to adjust `nfft` to be the next power of 2 above window size.

Comment: If that solved your problem you can accept your answer by clicking on the check mark symbol.

Comment: @MattL. I would but I can't before two days have expired ;) thanks!

Comment: OK, didn't know/remember that. Anyway, try to come back and accept, so everybody knows this case is closed.